# WinRT App consume NAV web services and got this message

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-nav

I did the following and got the below error msg:

The error message :

An exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: One or more errors occurred.
If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Question :

a)  What seems to be the problems in above code as I just wanted to retrieve a record.

b) Must use Async Methods in WinRT or Windows store app?

c) Will below code able to retrieve record from Navision?

```
-----1-------  Windows store App to access Nav Web Services

1.1 Added the service reference  in WinRT App 
1.2 Added a class1.cs in WinRT App


private async void btnImportCustomer_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Task _asyncCustomer = Class1.Customer.Listing.GetAsyncRecords("Y007");



    ###  encounterd error here: ####

   string  g_strmsg = _asyncCustomer.Result.No + " “ +_asyncCustomer.Result.Name;

}


-----2----------     Class1.cs use inside WinRT App Project:

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MobileNAVSalesSystem
{
    class Class1
    {
        public static string _webserviceurlpage = "http ://{0}:{1}/{2}/WS/{3}/Page/{4}";
        public static string _webserviceurlcodeunit = "http://{0}:{1}/{2}/WS/{3}/Codeunit/{4}";
        public static Uri _webserviceuripage = null;
        public static Uri _webserviceuricodeunit = null;


  #region Customer

        public class Customer
        {
            public class Card
            {
                //Do something for Card Type
            }

            public class Listing
            {
                public static wsCustomerList.Customer_List_PortClient GetService()
                {
                    _webserviceuripage = new Uri(string.Format(_webserviceurlpage, "msxxx", "7047", "DynamicsNAV_xxx", Uri.EscapeDataString("Global xxx  Pte. Ltd."), "Customer List"));

                    System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding _wSBinding = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding();
                    _wSBinding.Security.Mode = System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;
                    _wSBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = System.ServiceModel.HttpClientCredentialType.Windows;
                    _wSBinding.MaxBufferSize = Int32.MaxValue;
                    _wSBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = Int32.MaxValue;

                    //_wSBinding.UseDefaultWebProxy = false;

                    wsCustomerList.Customer_List_PortClient _ws = new wsCustomerList.Customer_List_PortClient(_wSBinding, new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(_webserviceuripage));
                    _ws.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Delegation;
                    _ws.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("xxx","xxxx", "companyName");
                    return _ws;
                }



   //-------------------------- Using Async Methods 

     public static async Task GetAsyncRecords(string _No)
     {
             wsCustomerList.Customer_List_PortClient _ws = GetService();
             wsCustomerList.Customer_List _List = (await _ws.ReadAsync(_No)).Customer_List;
             if (_ws.State == System.ServiceModel.CommunicationState.Opened)
                        await _ws.CloseAsync();
                    return _List;
      }

  public static async Task GetAsyncRecords(wsCustomerList.Customer_List_Filter[] _filters)
     {
            wsCustomerList.Customer_List_PortClient _ws = GetService();
             wsCustomerList.Customer_List[] _List;
             List _filterArray = new List();
                    _filterArray.AddRange(_filters);
                    _List = (await _ws.ReadMultipleAsync(_filterArray.ToArray(), null, 0)).ReadMultiple_Result1;
             if (_ws.State == System.ServiceModel.CommunicationState.Opened)
                        await _ws.CloseAsync();
                       return _List;
                }

  public static async Task GetAsyncRecords(wsCustomerList.Customer_List_Filter[] _filters, string _bookmarkkey)
     {
        wsCustomerList.Customer_List_PortClient _ws = GetService();
        wsCustomerList.Customer_List[] _List;
                    List _filterArray = new List();
        _filterArray.AddRange(_filters);
       _List = (await _ws.ReadMultipleAsync(_filterArray.ToArray(), _bookmarkkey, 0)).ReadMultiple_Result1;
        if (_ws.State == System.ServiceModel.CommunicationState.Opened)
                  await _ws.CloseAsync();
                return _List;
        }

  public static async Task GetAsyncRecords(wsCustomerList.Customer_List_Filter[] _filters, string _bookmarkkey, int _setsize)
    {
           wsCustomerList.Customer_List_PortClient _ws = GetService();
           wsCustomerList.Customer_List[] _List;
            List _filterArray = new List();
                    _filterArray.AddRange(_filters);
           _List = (await _ws.ReadMultipleAsync(_filterArray.ToArray(), _bookmarkkey, _setsize)).ReadMultiple_Result1;
            if (_ws.State == System.ServiceModel.CommunicationState.Opened)
                        await _ws.CloseAsync();
                    return _List;
                }

            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
//--- end namespace
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i know it is some time ago this question was posted, but others might stumble across it, so here goes:

**a) What seems to be the problems in above code as I just wanted to retrieve a record.**

it seems like your return type is incorrect.

**b) Must use Async Methods in WinRT or Windows store app?**

Yes, when using windows mobile platforms(windows store apps and windows phone apps), you have to use asynchronous calls.

**c) Will below code able to retrieve record from Navision?**

Hard to tell, but to me it seems like your data you try to retrieve is in a incorrect format. Ill give you a simple example from one of my current projects where I retrieve a login:

```
    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await call();
    }

    private async Task call()
    {
        BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
        WS_PortClient ws = new WS_PortClient(binding, new EndpointAddress("Webservice-URL"));

        binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;
        binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Ntlm;
        ws.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = cred;

        CheckLogin_Result s = await ws.CheckLoginAsync("parameter");
        string k = s.return_value.ToString();
        MessageDialog d = new MessageDialog(k, "message");
        await d.ShowAsync();
    }
```

Hope it helps!